# openshift 3 cloudflare routing

Tags: openshift, cloudflare

I am trying to transition from openshift v2 to v3. I believe I am repeating what I had set up before to enforce ssl and use my custom domain but it is not working.

I have created alias in my openshiftv3 project for: example.com, www.example.com

I have set up cname records on cloudflare: 
cname: @ 'is an alias of example.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com
cname: www 'is an alias of example.com'

My nameservers are already on my route53 domain hosting from hosting the previous version of my site.

this set up worked well for my v2 application, now it is jsut showing me 'Application is not available

The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.'

Could really use some guidance. Apologies if this is answered but only answers I could find are just showing to do what I have already set up.

Comment: What happens if you use ``curl -v -H Host:www.example.com http://example.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com`` IOW, use ``curl`` against the OpenShift cluster, but set ``Host`` header explicitly to your custom domain name. Also ``oc rsh`` into your container and see if you can do ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080``, changing port if necessary, and see if the application even responds from within the container.